# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with MaterialList

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am getting a `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.dexafree.materiallistviewexample.view.MaterialListView"`error when running my app.  I am using this library https://github.com/dexafree/MaterialList.  Here is my code.  I want to be sure I am not doing something wrong before I post an issue on Github.  Thanks!

Fragment1.java:

```
public class  FragmentTab1 extends ListFragment {

private Context mContext;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, null);

    mContext = getActivity();
    MaterialListView mListView = (MaterialListView) view.findViewById(R.id.material_listview);

    SimpleCard card = new SmallImageCard(mContext);
    card.setDescription("Description");
    card.setTitle("Title");
    card.setDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    mListView.add(card);

    return view;

}
```

FragmentTab1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.dexafree.materiallistviewexample.view.MaterialListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/material_listview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile ('com.github.dexafree:materiallist:2.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations'
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the path for class `MaterialListView`

Comment: Hmm that seems to have fixed something.  I changed `<com.dexafree.materiallistviewexample.view.MaterialListView`  to `<com.dexafree.materialList.view.MaterialListView`, but now I get a  `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: change the id of listview. see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Check the path of 1MaterialListView`. Seems you are using wrong path.

**Problem 2**

Change the id of your listview to this

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

or extend `Fragment` rather than `ListFragment`

Comment: I used your suggestions but now I get the same error again: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.dexafree.materiallist.view.MaterialListView"`

Comment: Saw its example on github. You should use Fragment instead on ListFragment and keep the id the way you want. Check the library linking once. Your app is not able to access the library somehow.

Comment: That seems to have done it!  It seems like ListFragment was the main problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi,How to get all values under the MaterialListView ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, change the package in your `FragmentTab1.xml`:

from :

```
com.dexafree.materiallistviewexample.view.MaterialListView
```

to:

```
com.dexafree.materiallist.view.MaterialListView
```

FragmentTab1.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.dexafree.materiallist.view.MaterialListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/material_listview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I used your suggestions but now I get the same error again: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.dexafree.materiallist.view.MaterialListView"`.  Is there something with the build.gradle that is causing this?